# SharePoint dont show username for locked document

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I cant understand my current situation.

I have one SharePoint 2013 Ent. When a file is locked and other user try to open it we have this message:

**FileName is locked for editing by 'another user'**

But the problem is why SharePoint not translate 'another user' to Domain user name???

I cant find information related to this issues.

Can somebody help me.

thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: did you checked wheather other user really editing the documents?

Comment: Hi,tks for your response. No user name name showing when a user take the file open.

Answer (score 1):

When a document is opened by a client program, Windows SharePoint Services puts a write lock on the document on the server. The write lock times out after 10 minutes. Users cannot modify the document during the time when the document is locked.

In a scenario where the program that opens the document unexpectedly quits or crashes and you try to open the document again before the write lock times out, the message that you receive says that the document is locked by another user. This behavior occurs even though you are user who previously opened the document.

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/899709

Also you can also use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/97332) to check what's wrong with file.

Comment: Hi,tks for your response. No user name name showing when a user take the file open.